# Same value updated by Python multiprocessing possible?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a global list of variables in Python, which need updating. Since this list is long, I would like to try using multiprocessing for faster computation. I've already figured out the basics, and it seems to work.

My question is: most variables are updated multiple times by different processes (using +=, so addition to the existing value). Is this a problem for parallel computing? Is there the possibility of a wrong outcome? Or will this work just fine?

Comment: Possibly looks like dangerous pattern, I recommend you to study more about multiprocessing or parallel programming in Python and try to learn some patterns.

Comment: Yes, multiple processes working on the same data structure is a problem. The `multiprocessing` package has some tools for it: [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)